# How to create custom system process to start along with database process?

Tags: oracle, process, system

I want to create a system process. so that whenever the database will start the process will also start running. the process will solely be for a specific application, which may be used for some monitoring, file writing activities etc. Can we create any such custom process?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

The details are probably operating system specific. Are you on a Posix system? Are you on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

If your system features some sort of file monitor, you could probably watch for execute access to the oracle database, or a file open on the database data.  This could even apply to a raw disk device, if that's how you're feeding Oracle tablespace.  On FreeBSD or Mac OS X, you'd use kqueue to monitor the tablespace, there's probably something similar in poll in Linux.